# how to update profile picture in navbar component after upload new photo in profile component using angular 4?

Tags: angular, upload, components

I'm using angular 4 and I have two components of navbar.component and profile.component. I can upload profile image from profile.component and in my navbar, I show the profile image. but when I upload an image in profile.component, the image won't be updated and I should refresh the page. how can i update it without page refresh?

here is profile.component:

```
user['profile_pic'] = this.new_profile_pic_name;
}
this.authService.updateProfile(user).subscribe(data => {
  if (!data.success) {
    consolle.log('err')
  } else {
    console.log('success')
  }
});
```

and this is navbar.component:

```
ngOnInit()
{
this.authService.userProfile().subscribe(user => {
  if (!user.success) {
    console.log('err')
  } else {
    this.user_id = user.user.rows[0].id;
    if (user.user.rows[0].profile_pic) {
      this.profile_pic = this.profile_pic_dir + 
       user.user.rows[0].profile_pic;
    }
  }
});
}
```

and navbar html:

```
<button [md-menu-trigger-for]="user" md-icon-button class="ml-xs">
  <img [src]="profile_pic" class="img" *ngIf="profile_pic">
  <img src="assets/images/profile/no-pic.jpg" class="img" 
  *ngIf="!profile_pic">
</button>
```